# Need to Put all Modules in One Folder - 2 Sets of Python "Frameworks" Installed on Mac? (System/Library/Frameworks and Library/Frameworks)

Tags: python

I have two sets of Python installed on my Mac.

"System/Library/Frameworks" and "Library/Frameworks"

I have trying to put all my Python modules in one folder. Currently, this is what's shown when I dump my sys.path:

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.21-py2.7.egg
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0-py2.7.egg
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo-2.0.1_-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytz-2011k-py2.7.egg
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13-py2.7.egg
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL

Can I delete one "copy" of the Python "framework"? And will copying all module files over work?

I have been using this computer for some years now so I may have unintentionally done something that caused this.

Comment: Not sure about your specific question, but you may want to check out [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) for the ability to create multiple, isolated Python environments.

Comment: just to add on, I can't seem to echo both PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME (nor any of the Python env variables), though I was able to see them through the interactive console by importing sys.path and dumping it. Where can I set these variables (without overriding it outright by redeclaring them)?

Comment: why don't you just remove the destination directory and leave the originals intact.  Or did you move the files rather than copy them?

Comment: btw, moving files from your system python installation will likely break things.

Comment: @kev, please start a new question rather than asking a different question in comments.